# Remove characters after dash in a mixed string in R

Tags: r

```
data
  V9         V10 V11    
1 neutral -0.204 PRKCZ-AS1
2 neutral  0.037 FAAP20-AS1   
3 neutral  0.041 PRKCZ-AS1    
4 neutral  0.041 FAAP20-ZA12   
5 neutral  0.133 PRKCZ-SAS13    
6 neutral  0.133 FAAP20-SAS9999
```

This is my data frame, a column of which include dash-separated strings. I want to remove the dash and the followed characters.
Finally, I want an output as follows:

```
data
  V9         V10 V11    
1 neutral -0.204 PRKCZ
2 neutral  0.037 FAAP20 
3 neutral  0.041 PRKCZ  
4 neutral  0.041 FAAP20   
5 neutral  0.133 PRKCZ   
6 neutral  0.133 FAAP20
```

**Reproducible sample data**

```
structure(list(V9 = c("neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral"), V10 = c(-0.204, 0.037, 0.041, 0.041, 0.133, 
0.133), V11 = c("PRKCZ-AS1", "FAAP20-AS1", "PRKCZ-AS1", "FAAP20-ZA12", 
"PRKCZ-SAS13", "FAAP20-SAS9999")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `tidyverse` you can just use `stringr::str_remove`...

```
data %>% mutate(V11 = str_remove(V11, "-.+"))

       V9    V10    V11
1 neutral -0.204  PRKCZ
2 neutral  0.037 FAAP20
3 neutral  0.041  PRKCZ
4 neutral  0.041 FAAP20
5 neutral  0.133  PRKCZ
6 neutral  0.133 FAAP20
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
data$V11 <- sub("-.*", "", data$V11)
```

---

Or with `trimws`

```
data$V11 <- trimws(data$V11, whitespace = '-.*')
```

Answer (score 2):

We colud use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  separate("V11", c("V11", "V11a")) %>% 
  select(-V11a)
```

output:

```
  V9         V10 V11   
  <chr>    <dbl> <chr> 
1 neutral -0.204 PRKCZ 
2 neutral  0.037 FAAP20
3 neutral  0.041 PRKCZ 
4 neutral  0.041 FAAP20
5 neutral  0.133 PRKCZ 
6 neutral  0.133 FAAP20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this solution, though not as brilliant & concise as dear @akrun's:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

str_locate(df$V11, "-") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(start) %>%
  bind_cols(df) %>%
  mutate(V11 = str_sub(V11, 1L, start-1))

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  start V9         V10 V11   
* <int> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> 
1     6 neutral -0.204 PRKCZ 
2     7 neutral  0.037 FAAP20
3     6 neutral  0.041 PRKCZ 
4     7 neutral  0.041 FAAP20
5     6 neutral  0.133 PRKCZ 
6     7 neutral  0.133 FAAP20
```